# Sharing transports in Mass Transit 5.2.1

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to use the InMemoryBus transport in unit tests with 2 bus instances (same process). One of the bus instances should publish an event and the other one consume it.

What I need, I think, is the Shared Transport feature documented here http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/transports.html but it seems no longer available in version 5.2.1. Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple bus instances with a shared in-memory transport are no longer supported. You can use a single bus instance with multiple receive endpoints if you need to test multiple consumers in the same process.

I'm guessing that you're upgrading from a much older version of MT, since that ability was removed quite some time ago.

Comment: I'm a new user, I actually ended up using multiple receive endpoints after some digging, I just got confused from the documentation :-). Thanks for your aswer and the amazing work with MT.